# How to properly map an array to access properties in its nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects:

```
const array = [ 
   { 
      "fieldA":"abc",
      "fieldB":[ 
         { 
            "fieldC":{ 
               "fieldD":"I am here!"
            }
         },
         { 
            "fieldC":{ 
               "fieldD":"And I am here!",
            },
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I access the `fieldD` property value of each object in the array?

What I've tried:

```
console.log(array.map(({ fieldB }) =>
    fieldB.map(({ fieldC: { fieldD } }) => ({ fieldD }))
))
```

However, this returns one parent array, which contains an array at it's `0` index, which contains objects with keys named `fieldD`.

I would like to return an array with just the values, ie:

```
// expected output
[ 'I am here!', 'And I am here!' ]
```

Is this possible with `.map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it. Instead of mapping `fieldD` to an object with `=> ({fieldD})`, you can map it to its value with `=> fieldD`. For removing the inner arrays, you can use `.flatMap()`, which will map your inner array contents to one larger parent:

```js
const array = [ { "fieldA":"abc", "fieldB":[ { "fieldC":{ "fieldD":"I am here!" } }, { "fieldC":{ "fieldD":"And I am here!", }, } ] } ];

console.log(array.flatMap(({ fieldB }) =>
    fieldB.map(({ fieldC: { fieldD } }) => fieldD)
))
```

A more browser-friendly version (as [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility) is relatively new to JS) would be to use a double `.map()`, and then `.concat()` to flatten your array:

```js
const array = [ { "fieldA":"abc", "fieldB":[ { "fieldC":{ "fieldD":"I am here!" } }, { "fieldC":{ "fieldD":"And I am here!", }, } ] } ];

console.log([].concat(...array.map(({ fieldB }) =>
    fieldB.map(({ fieldC: { fieldD } }) => fieldD)
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const array = [ 
    { 
       "fieldA":"abc",
       "fieldB":[ 
          { 
             "fieldC":{ 
                "fieldD":"I am here!"
             }
          },
          { 
             "fieldC":{ 
                "fieldD":"And I am here!",
             },
          }
       ]
    }
 ];

 let result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
     let result = item.fieldB.map( elem => elem.fieldC.fieldD);
     return result;
 }, []);

 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const array = [ 
       { 
          "fieldA":"abc",
          "fieldB":[ 
             { 
                "fieldC":{ 
                   "fieldD":"I am here!"
                }
             },
             { 
                "fieldC":{ 
                   "fieldD":"And I am here!",
                },
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
    
    console.log(array.map(({ fieldB }) =>
        fieldB.map(({ fieldC: { fieldD } }) => (fieldD))
    )[0])
```

I hope this code helpful for you case. But It's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion to achieve your goal:

```js
const array = [ 
   { 
      "fieldA":"abc",
      "fieldB":[ 
         { 
            "fieldC":{ 
               "fieldD":"I am here!"
            }
         },
         { 
            "fieldC":{ 
               "fieldD":"And I am here!",
            },
         }
      ]
   }
];

const findField = function(obj, field){
    for(let key in obj){
      if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
        return findField(obj[key], field);
      }else if(key == field){
        return obj[key];
      }
    }  
}

array.forEach(obj => {
  console.log(findField(obj, 'fieldD'));
});
```